# Android compability for NDK compiled apps

Tags: android, android-ndk, cross-compiling

The question may sounds super stupid but i didn't find any offical answer and this bug https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/272 made me even more confuse.

If I compile a C program with ndk with plataform version 27 will it work on older versions of android?

Answer (score 0):

No. NDK API level is equivalent to minSdkVersion: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/user/common_problems.md#target-api-set-higher-than-device-api

The static version of the C library can be used in an executable, but will cause issues if it is used in an app since libc has already been loaded by the zygote and you will have conflicting copies of global data structures.

Note that even with a plain executable, statically linking libc can cause issues with networking since libc delegates some aspects of that to netd, and that communication protocol is only guaranteed to work when the version of libc matches the version of netd.